# Git version control certain files

Tags: git, version-control

*1000% certain there is a question about it, I just have no idea how I should google it.*

**The problem.**

I'd like git to grab the files I commit, but only control the version of some of the files (snippets, scripts and json configs), I would like git to grab .dll libraries and other stuff, but since they are binary, git will literally copy binary files and take up big portion of the space in repo, I don't want git to do that.

For example. I have

- Script.cs
- Config.json
- SystemLib.cs
- Library_ver1.2.dll

If I was to update Library to version 1.3, git will store ver1.2 and ver1.3. Lib I don't literally care about, so I only want it to be stored, not versioned. I only want git to version control *.cs and *.json files in this example.

Comment: Try git lfs. You can setup your own lfs server with https://github.com/git-lfs/lfs-test-server, which can run in the same local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ElpieKay, I've researched LFS and it does exactly what I wanted, therefore resolved this issue.